# gRPC - Keep a stream connection alive in Python

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to convert a C# app into a Python app and I am having issues with gRPC.

I need to keep a stream connection alive while the application is running, this app receive broadcast messages from the service.

This is the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "mcGrpcService";

message mcCommandRequest {
  int32 id = 1;
  string content = 2;
}

message mcCommandResponse {
  bool succes = 1;
  string message = 2;
}

service grpcCommsService {
  rpc XchangeCommand (mcCommandRequest) returns (mcCommandResponse);
  rpc XchangeBroadcast (stream google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream mcCommandRequest);
}
```

This is the C# code:

```cs
private readonly Channel? _channel;
private readonly grpcCommsService.grpcCommsServiceClient _client;

public McGrpcClient(string host, int port) {
    _channel = new Channel(host, port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    _client = new grpcCommsService.grpcCommsServiceClient(_channel);
}

public bool Connect(Action<mcCommandRequest> onBroadcastReceived) {
    OnBroadcastReceived = onBroadcastReceived;

    var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    _broadcastTask = Task.Run(async () => {
        var broadcastCall = _client.XchangeBroadcast(cancellationToken: token);
        while (await broadcastCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(token)) {
            try {
                var broadcastMessage = broadcastCall.ResponseStream.Current;
                OnBroadcastReceived?.Invoke(broadcastMessage);
            }
            catch {
                // todo implement error handling
                throw;
            }
        }
    }, token);
    return true;
}
```

And this is my current Python code:

```py
async def read_broadcast(request: Iterator[xchange__pb2.mcCommandRequest], stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        msg = await request.next()
        print("Broadcast received: ", msg.message)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

def connect(stub, stop_event):
    iterator = None
    request = stub.XchangeBroadcast(iterator)
    asyncio.run(
        read_broadcast(request, stop_event)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:9999")
    stub = grpcCommsServiceStub(channel)
    stop_event = threading.Event()

    connect(stub, stop_event)

    input()
    stop_event.set()
    channel.close()
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Exception has occurred: _MultiThreadedRendezvous
> <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
> details = "Exception iterating requests!"
> debug_error_string = "None">

I have tried also with `for msg in request` and same error.

Looking at server logs it seems the connection is closed just after:

`request = stub.XchangeBroadcast(iterator)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the C# service is waiting for client requests stream before sending any response stream, and in your python code i couldn't find where you actually instantiate requests to the service from your python (client) app.
Seems like the actual sending of a request for streaming is missing.

In C#, you didn't need to manually send the request because the client stub automatically sent it for you. But in Python, especially in asynchronous gRPC, you need to explicitly handle it.

Here's what happens:

- `stub.XchangeBroadcast(iterator)` initializes the RPC call and returns an object representing ongoing or completed RPC. In your case, you pass None to XchangeBroadcast, which is intended to be a stream of requests, but it's not necessary in your scenario because you're using an empty message for that RPC. Essentially, you're not sending any initial request.
- `read_broadcast(request, stop_event)` awaits messages from the service, but it is not clear whether you're handling the request stream to the server properly.

I would try to handle the streams in different way, maybe something like:

```py
async def read_broadcast(stub, stop_event):
    empty = empty_pb2.Empty()  # Empty message as the request
    
    try:
        async for msg in stub.XchangeBroadcast([empty]):  # Initialize the stream and await incoming messages
            if stop_event.is_set():
                break
            print(f"Broadcast received: {msg.content}")
    except grpc.RpcError as e:
        print(f"gRPC error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: "try" and "maybe" are usually not words that are included in definitive and unambiguous answers.  If you need clarification to provide a definitive answer you should ask them as comments first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amit, I've tried something similar before but I'm getting this error: `'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got _MultiThreadedRendezvous` Server streams to all connected clients at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a way looking at grpc repo examples:

```py
def msg_received(msg):
    print("Broadcast received: {} - {}".format(msg.id, msg.content))

async def run():
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel("localhost:9999") as channel:
        stub = grpcCommsServiceStub(channel)

        stream = stub.XchangeBroadcast()
        while True:
            try:
                msg = await stream.read()
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                partial_callback = functools.partial(msg_received, msg)
                loop.call_soon_threadsafe(partial_callback)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            except grpc.aio.AioRpcError as e:
                print("Error: ", e)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(run(),))
    run_thread.start()
```

`await stream.read()` blocks the thread until some message is received and the connection is kept alive.